# Concatenating string and int in printf - C

Tags: c, printf

I have the following code:

```
#define ERROR_MSG "Error: there was an error "
#define IN_LINE_MSG "in line"
int line = 0;
```

how can I concatenate those 3 using `printf` so I will get the following printed:

```
"Error: there was an error in line 0"
```

Comment: You mean something like `printf(ERROR_MSG IN_LINE_MSG " %d", line)`?

Comment: Are you asking how to print integers and strings with printf? What have you tried? Chapter 1 of your favourite C programming book is really good btw.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [format specifiers](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/format-specifiers-in-c/) for `printf`

This should be it: `printf("%s%s %d", ERROR_MSG, IN_LINE_MSG, line)`

Here, `%s` stands for string and `%d` stands for a digit. Then those three arguments after the string are passed in to take the place of those specifiers, in order.

Answer (score 2):

```
printf(ERROR_MSG IN_LINE_MSG " %d", line);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ERROR_MSG "Error: there was an error "
#define IN_LINE_MSG "in line"
int line = 0;

int main()
{
   printf("%s%s %d", ERROR_MSG, IN_LINE_MSG, line);
}
```

Output:

```
Error: there was an error in line 0
```

or

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ERROR_MSG "Error: there was an error "
#define IN_LINE_MSG "in line"
int line = 0;

int main()
{
   printf(ERROR_MSG IN_LINE_MSG " %d", line);
}
```

Output:

```
Error: there was an error in line 0
```